# How to make two bootstrap modal forms submit independently?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap modal forms on the same html document.

I want to get these forms to work independently, however, `form 1` does not
submit and `form2` submits the data entered in both forms.

How do I get these forms to work independently without interfering with the actions
of one another?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!------------------------form1----------------------------------->
<div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="panel-title" id="registerLabel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Register</h4>
                    </div>

                    <form id="form1" action="register.php " method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 5px;">




                           <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer" style="margin-bottom:-14px;" data-target="form1"  >
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Send"/>
                                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>-->
                            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Clear" />
                                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>-->
                            <button style="float: right;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
   <!------------------------form2----------------------------------->
<div class="modal fade" id="buy" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="buyLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="panel-title" id="buyLabel"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Buy</h4>
                    </div>

                    <form id="form2" action="buy.php " method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 5px;">




                           <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                    <input class="form-control" item="item" placeholder="Name" type="text" required />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer" style="margin-bottom:-14px;" data-target="form1"  >
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Send"/>
                                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>-->
                            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Clear" />
                                <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>-->
                            <button style="float: right;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Where do your <form> tags end? I can only see the opening tags.

Comment: Please do not link to a site which will most likely change in the future or the link changes causing a dead link as that has no use for future users with possibly similar issues. Add the relvant code to the question and if possible add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) (or similar) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I added your HTML if there is any additional *relevant* code to be added please, i.e: scripts, add them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the forms ending somewhere.

Please close form before starting another so that it will be independent.